# If I use a shared hosting, can I really set all value on my php.ini file in the runtime?

Tags: php

Something like:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: Why not try it? You won't get kicked from your host for trying it.

Comment: I don't have it yet. I have a choice, either shared hosting or dedicated, that's why I asked this.

Comment: You can always go with a VPS. I don't know if I can reference VPS's hosts here, someone can edit if not, but directspace is a cheap one, $6/mon for a good VM or Linode is a good one as well, but a bit more money. But yea, you can look online and find some decent VPS. That way you have full control of the server and don't have to worry about the shared host non-sense and is a great option if you don't need a dedicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the list of all the `php.ini` directives, and where they can be changed from:

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Comment: @Bagong21 -- yep, should be.  Of course, some options depend on other elements of the server set-up, and may not *work* without the co-operation of the hosting provider, and a hosting provider can restrict what can be over-ridden in `.htaccess` files, for example, but if it's marked `PHP_INI_USER` or `PHP_INI_ALL` here, you can set it with `ini_set()` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set some of them, others can not be set for security reasons, such as [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php).